# Conditionally chaining HTTP requests in angular

Tags: json, angular, rxjs

on a webpage built with angular (4.0.0) I'm calling a method on a server using a POST request. Usually the server returns a result directly, but sometimes it returns an "async_id", with which I can call another method that waits for a result.

I've got an angular service that has an execute() method like this:

```
public execute(module: string, command: string, params: any) {
    // build body
    let body = 'abc';

    // do request
    return this.http.post(this._url, body)
        .map(data => data.json())
        .switchMap(json => {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty("result") && json.result.hasOwnProperty("async_id")) {
                return this.execute('server', 'wait_for_finished',
                    {'async_id': json.result.async_id}).map(val => val.json());
            }
            return Observable.of(json);
        })
        .flatMap(json => {
            // do something with JSON
            // ..
            return json.result;
        });
}
```

So I'm calling post() on the Http object and transform the response to JSON. Within switchMap I check, whether an async_id is given. If yes, I just recursively call the method again, otherwise I return the JSON object. Finally, I'm trying to do something with the results, but I get the following error:

```
Property 'result' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What does `console.log(json);` say in the `flatmap` method?

Comment: console.log(json) outputs the correct json object. I just tested: by commenting out the if clause and thus always returning Observable.of(json), it works fine (of course without the async functionality that I want). For that I have to change the flatMap to map as well. So the problem seems to be the recursive method call?

Comment: Should you be mapping the value at the end of the recursive call? `return this.execute('server', 'wait_for_finished', {'async_id': json.result.async_id}).map(val => val.json());`

Comment: Funny enough, just doing a second HTTP call within switchMap and not calling the method recursively works fine. So I guess I'm going that way. Thanks for your help!